# Converting Complex SQL to Python Pandas Merge and/or Join

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, pandas

I currently have a Python script which converts two pandas `DataFrames` to tables in a `SQLite` database in memory, before reading reading and running SQL code on the tables.  I would like the script to be more "Pythonic", merging and/or joining the `DataFrames`, but am having a difficult time finding Python code examples for the equivalent of `SELECT`ing specific, and not all, elements from both tables, along with `FROM`, `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clauses.  I am fairly new to Python, and being the Guinea Pig of my department, so if I can get this working, it will become a template for MANY more scripts from my partners in my work group.  Actual element names have been changed do to proprietary information, but the structure is the same.  Thanks in advance for the help!

```
SELECT
   dfE.Element05 AS [Alt Element05],
   dfE.Element03 AS [Alt Element03],
   dfE.Element04 AS [Alt Element04],
   dfN.Element03,
   dfN.Element04,
   dfN.Element08,
   dfN.Element09,
   dfN.Element10,
   dfN.Element17,
   dfN.Element18,
   dfN.Element19,
   dfN.Element20,
   dfN.Element23,
   dfN.Element26,
   dfN.Element13
FROM dfE INNER JOIN dfN ON (dfE.Element17 = dfN.Element17) AND (dfE.Element20 = dfN.Element20)
WHERE (((dfN.Element03)<>dfE.Element03))
GROUP BY
   dfE.Element05,
   dfE.Element03,
   dfE.Element04,
   dfN.Element03,
   dfN.Element04,
   dfN.Element08,
   dfN.Element09,
   dfN.Element10,
   dfN.Element17,
   dfN.Element18,
   dfN.Element19,
   dfN.Element20,
   dfN.Element23,
   dfN.Element26,
   dfN.Element13
ORDER BY
   dfE.Element03,
   dfN.Element03,
   dfN.Element08
```

Answer (score 1):

I would start by copying the DataFrames that you want to join and selecting the specific columns there. I have included "Element17" & "Element20" from dfE because you need to have it when joining.

Ex.

```
df1 = dfE['Element05,'Element03','Element04','Element17','Element20'].copy()
```

In order to rename the columns use the following:

```
df1.rename(columns={'Element05':'Alt Element05','Element03':'Alt Element03','Element04':'Alt Element04'},inplace=True)
```

Once you have the other df set up (lets name it `df2`) you would use `pd.merge()` to join them as you would in SQL. *When using pd.merge, the columns on which you are going to join have to have the same name or it won't work! (Lets say df1['A'] shares the same data as df2['B'] and you want to join the DataFrames. You would have to change the name on one of the DataFrames so that it is equal to the column name of the Df you are joining to or it won't work.)

Ex.

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df1,how='inner',on=['Element17','Element20'])
```

For the `Where` I would do the following.

```
df3= df3[df3['Alt Element03']!=df3['Element']]
```

For `Order By` you could use .sort() but I'm not comfortable with giving you advice on how to use it as I haven't used it much.

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have questions.

*** This might not be the best way to do things. I apologize beforehand if I'm leading you to develop bad habits. I'm new to python as well!